# Targets dependency missing in rmarkdown file which is included in another rmarkdown file

Tags: r, targets-r-package

I have a targets pipeline that trains multiple models and in the end creates a flexdashboard (or Rmd file) that summarizes the models.

For the summary I have an Rmd file that is included in the targets pipeline using `tarchetypes::tar_render()`. The dependency management of the output rmarkdown itself works as expected, the catch however is, that it includes an expanded template Rmd file that summarizes a single model using `knitr::knit_expand()` and this template file has additional dependencies that are not caught by targets (ie output depends on varimp1 and 2 in the picture below).

Can I include the dependencies manually or is there a better way to create this dynamically created Rmd file (one section for each model)?

### MWE

The below pipeline replicates the problem.
The ultimate output is the output.Rmd file that uses the template.Rmd file once for each model.
The dependency for this pipeline is this:

[image: Dependency Graph]

Note that the output target does not depend on the varimp1/2 targets (instead the template_file (itself a dependency of output) uses the varimp1/2 targets), therefore the output might not be created as varimp1/2 might not exist or might be out of date.

`_targets.R`

```
library(targets)
library(tarchetypes)

# dummy functions
train_model <- function(id) {
  return(id)
}
get_var_imp <- function(mdl, seed) {
  # note the seed argument is used here only to easily change
  # and invalidate the results...
  set.seed(seed)
  return(data.frame(x = runif(1), y = runif(1)))
}

list(
  tar_target(model1, train_model(id = "model1")),
  tar_target(model2, train_model(id = "model2")),
  
  tar_target(varimp1, get_var_imp(model1, seed = 1)),
  tar_target(varimp2, get_var_imp(model2, seed = 2)),
  
  tar_target(template_file, "template.Rmd", format = "file"),
  tar_render(output, "output.Rmd")
)
```

`output.Rmd`

````
---
title: "Output"
output: rmarkdown::html_document
---

# This is a general section

```{R}
# these dependencies are working
model1 <- tar_read(model1)
model2 <- tar_read(model2)
```

For each var model create a new chapter

```{r, echo=FALSE}
models <- c("model1", "model2")
NAME_MAP <- c(
  model1 = "A first Model",
  model2 = "A second Model"
)
txt <- sapply(models, \(target_name) knitr::knit_expand(tar_read(template_file)))
```

`r paste(knitr::knit(text = txt), collapse = '\n')`
````

`template.Rmd`

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
# this dependency is picked up because it already exists
# in output.Rmd
mdl <- tar_read_raw("{{target_name}}")
mdl_name <- NAME_MAP[["{{target_name}}"]]

# this dependency is not picked up!  =================================
vi <- tar_read_raw(gsub("model", "varimp", "{{target_name}}"))
```

# Model `{{target_name}}` - `r mdl_name`

Feature Imps are

```{r, echo=FALSE}
# or do something with mdl
vi
```
````

The resulting document will look like this

[image: Resulting document]

Comment: As a workaround, you could write a `tar_load()` in the main document for each target included in the child document. Then just reference those targets as R objects in the child document without any need for additional `tar_read()`s or `tar_load()`s.